# Pandas drop group column after groupby.apply(..)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

```
        uid  iid  val
uid                 
1   1    1    5   5.5
2   3    1    4   3.5
2   2    1    4   3.5
2   7    1    4   3.5
2   9    1    4   3.5
2   11   1    4   3.5
```

From the dataframe above, I want to remove the first column, which is:

```
uid
1
2
2
2
2
2
```

and extract

```
    uid  iid  val

1    1    5   5.5
3    1    4   3.5
2    1    4   3.5
7    1    4   3.5
9    1    4   3.5
11   1    4   3.5
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can avoid including the `uid` in the index in the first place by passing `group_keys=False` to the `groupby`

```
df.groupby('uid', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.tail(len(x) // 5))

   uid  iid  val
4    1    5  5.5
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) or [`droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html):

```
df = df.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)


df = df.reset_index(level='uid', drop=True)
```

Or:

```
df.index = df.index.droplevel(0)
```

Comment: As of version 0.24.0 we can simply use `df.droplevel(0)` and keep our method chain rolling.

Answer (score 0):

you can set `as_index` as `False` to remove the index from the grouped by df.

```
df.groupby('uid', as_index=False)
```